# php Removing onclick handler from anchor tags

Tags: php, regex

Any one have any function for stripping onclick,onfocus attribute from anchor tags? i basically want to remove instances of javascript from anchor tags in a php string

Comment: btw, i know there is html parsers out there and purifiers but thats overkill

Comment: are you sure it's overkill? Because if it's for security, proper anti-XSS stripping is really necessary

Comment: im not trying to prevent xss... i already have some<a> in database. some have javascript... i need to strip this javascrip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanx Charles... i know its overkill but html purifier just took this

```
require_once '../library/HTMLPurifier.auto.php';

$config = HTMLPurifier_Config::createDefault();
$config->set('Core.Encoding', 'UTF-8'); // replace with your encoding
$config->set('HTML.Doctype', 'HTML 4.01 Transitional'); // replace with your doctype                        
$purifier = new HTMLPurifier($config);        
$ret= $purifier->purify(retNotification($bo));
```

thats all i had to do... $ret returns html safe as expected

alternatively... i have answered this question here [PHP Getting and Setting tag attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5294691/php-getting-and-setting-tag-attributes)

Answer (score 1):

as per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags), you should never use regex for html. You should consider using [DOMDocument](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php).

Comment: gone to that post and couldnt find anything to answer my question. just libraries etc.... anyone with a function i can pass a php string and it removes the onclick handlers...

Answer (score 1):

While you can do this manually through the DOM, you should seriously consider using a HTML filtering tool like [HTML Purifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/) as a **whitelist**, only allowing known-good elements and attributes through.