# PHP Getting and Setting tag attributes

Tags: php, dom

im being played by php and DomDocument.... basically i have some html saved in db. With anchor tags with different urls.... i want to force anchor tag hrefs not within allowedurl list to be replaced with #

eg

```
$allowed_url_basenames = array('viewprofile.php','viewalbum.php');
```

sample content from db1

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td valign="top">
            <a href="viewprofile.php?userid=780">Edrine Kasasa </a> has &nbsp;
        </td>
        <td valign="top"> 
        invited 10 friend(s) to veepiz using the <a href="invite.php">Invite Tool</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

i want a php function that will leave first anchor tag href intact and change the second to href='#'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be pretty straight-forward.

First, let's grab all of the anchor tags.  `$doc` is the document you've created [with your HTML as the source](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php).

```
$anchors = $doc->getElementsByTagName('a');
```

Now we'll go through them one-by-one and inspect the `href` attribute.  Let's *pretend* that the function `contains_bad_url` returns `true` when the passed string is on your blacklist.  You'll need to write that yourself.

```
foreach($anchors as $anchor)
    if($anchor->hasAttribute('href') && contains_bad_url($anchor->getAttribute('href'))) {
        $anchor->setAttribute('href', '#');
    }
}
```

Tada.  That should be all there is to it.  You should be able to [get the results back as an XML string](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.savexml.php) and do whatever you need to do with the rest.

Answer (score 1):

Thanx Charles.... came up with this

```
function contains_bad_urls($href,$allowed_urls)
{
    $x=pathinfo($href);
    $bn=$x['filename'];
    if (array_search($bn,$allowed_urls)>-1)
    {
        return false;
    }   
    return true;
}

function CleanHtmlUrls($str)
{
    $allow_urls = array('viewprofile','viewwall');//change these to whatever filename
    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    $doc->loadHTML($str);
    $doc->formatOutput = true;
    $anchors = $doc->getElementsByTagName('a');
    foreach($anchors as $anchor)
    {
    $anchor->setAttribute('onclick','#');
        if(contains_bad_urls($anchor->getAttribute('href'),$allow_urls)) 
        {
            $anchor->setAttribute('href', '#');
        }
    }
    $ret=$doc->saveHTML();
    return $ret
}
```